# Gray box around image, bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I've tried setting "outline: none", messed with the border, and I can't seem to fix it. You can view the page at: https://spring-resonance-4984.bss.design/. The reason I'm linking is because I don't know what part of the page is incorrect or needs to be added. I will update this with additional information if someone can help me.

Comment: The question here should be, why should I add a background-image style to an image element?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your markup, it's because you are technically using an `<img>` tag, which [expects a valid `src` attribute to be set per the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element).

```
<img class="img-fluid" style="...background-url(...);...">
```

If you are using CSS to set the image, which in your case you are via the `background-url` property, then you should likely use a `<div>` element instead:

```
<div class="img-fluid" style="..."></div>
```

Otherwise, if you still want to explicitly use an `<img>` tag, you should either:

- Set the `src` attribute to your specified image.
- Ignore the `src` attribute, but explicitly set an `alt` property (of something like `alt=' '`) to hide the surrounding border (this is not recommended, but it *should* get rid of your border issue)

Comment: This is correct, I changed it to DIV and it looks good now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's an img tag without a src, hence it looks a bit funky.
Either change the tag to div or set the src attribute of the img tag (instead of styling the background).

```html
<div class="img-fluid" style="outline: none;background-image: url(&quot;/assets/img/CircuitSoft_White.png?h=1b8c81e3c8ae0db6dac138a0839bf6bc&quot;);width: 160px;height: 76px;color: rgba(255,255,255,0);background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);margin: 0px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a `background-image` property on an `<img>` tag.

Just set the `src` of your `img` tag to the URL that you are linking to on your `background-image` property

[image]